# What 2 × 2 matrix M satisfies M ∗ [x, y]=[y, x] for all vectors [x, y]?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, self-learning

> What 2 × 2 matrix M satisfies M ∗ [x, y]=[y, x] for all vectors [x,
>   y]?

Could someone explain to me, step by step, what I should do here? I have an exam but I am stuck with this one. I am a newbie, but I like it to be honest, although the teachers explanation are way too complex for me at the moment.

I would appreciate a step by step approach, because that's what I am missing at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a $2 \times 2$ matrix so that

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ x \end{pmatrix}$$

You could start by seeing what happens when this matrix acts on the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b \\ d \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Oeh, I think I am close now... Thanks for the clear explanation, yet I don't understand the last one. Okay, we have a,c and b,d now, but then what? Why not use x,y instead?

Comment: The vector $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ can be expressed in terms of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$: $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = x \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + y \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, I got that, but what are a,c and b,d then? How does that answer the question, because the question tells me to get = x,y...

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ are the entries in the matrix. You're trying to find their values so that the transformation works for ANY vector.

Comment: So basically, you need to prove the columns AC and BD and get their outcome based on x = 1, x = 0 and y = 1 and y = 0, correct?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment is probably $M \times \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y\\x\end{pmatrix}$. (Note, that vectors must be column, otherwise the multiplivation does not make sense.)

A general $2\times 2$ matrix matrix is of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, so the LHS of the equation is $M \times \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax+by\\cx+dy\end{pmatrix} $ and comparing this to the RHS you get system of 2 equations and 4 parameters $$ax + by = y \, \&\,  cx+ dy = x.$$

Now, the equation has to work for column vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, which gives the result $a=d=0$ and $b=c=1$.

Comment: Love the example. Thanks man, appreciated and upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
This is because for any $x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ we have that
$$Mx = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This does not seem like "step-by-step" to me..

Comment: It is not step by step indeed, but I think I get it. I still don't understand why we use 0,1 and 1,0 in M, though. The fact that we are putting numbers that we didn't get in the question, confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

For any ($2 \times 2$) matrix  $M$ you can see from the definition of matrix multiplication that $M \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ equals the first column of $M$. Also, $M \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ equals the second column of $M$. But the requirements  say what these should equal, namely the vector with interchanged coordinates. So we get

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks, Henno. You said that "you can see from the definition that M (1,0), yet I can't see that haha. How do I know that? I am missing this piece of information.

Comment: Write out the definition equations for $M$ times a vector $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$. What happens if $x=1$ and $y=0$?